# If $X$ is a Banach space then a ball is closed

Tags: functional-analysis

In the proof of this proposition:

> Let $X$ a Banach reflexive space and $Y\subset X$ closed subspace. Then $Y$ is Banach reflexive space.

There is this sentence:

> $Y$ is strongly closed (normed closed) in $X$, so $Y \cap \ B_X = B_Y$ is normed closed and convex (**because $B_Y$ is a ball of Banach space $Y$**).

My question is: Why he used $Y$ Banach? Is not true that a ball is ever closed, even if the space is only a normed space and not Banach?

Comment: If $Y$ _were_ not a Banach space, that would _signify_ that $Y$ is not closed, hence there exists a fundamental sequence in $Y,$ say $(y_n),$ that does not converge in $Y$ (but since $X$ is Banach, $y_n \to y$ for a $y \in X$). Every fundamental sequence is bounded, hence by multiplying by a large scalar we reach taht $\|y_n\| \leq 1/2$ and in particular $\|y\| \leq 1/2$ and everything lives in $B_X;$ therefore, the sequence $y_n$ is in $B_Y$ and is convergent to a point $x$  that is not in $B_Y.$

Comment: For a silly example, take the set $\mathbb{Q}\cap [-1,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$. This  is the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{Q}$ but is not a closed subset under the $\mathbb{R}$ topology.

Answer (score 1):

> **Lemma :** Let $X$ be a Banach space. Then, $Y \subset X$ is also a Banach space if and only if $Y$ is closed.

This is why he initially used that $Y$ is a Banach space, if I understand the first part of your question correctly.

For a proof at that Lemma, work as :

$( \Rightarrow )$ Let $(y_n)$ be a Cauchy Sequence in $Y$. But $Y$ is closed, which means that $y_n \to y \in Y$. What does that tell us ?

$(\Leftarrow)$ Let $Y$ be a Banach space. This means that the space is complete, meaning that any given sequence (Cauchy) $y_n \in Y$ converges to some $y \in Y$. But what definition yields from that ?

---

As for the ball, no, it is not true that a (unit) Ball $B_X$ is closed in any given space $X$ (Banach or not). If we are referring to a closed (unit) ball 
$$B_X = \{x \in X : \|x \| \leq 1\}$$
then this is indeed a closed set.

Comment: From context, is it not true that he is referring to the *closed* unit ball, $$B_X = \{ x \in X : ||x|| \leq 1\}?$$  If this is indeed the case, then it would be a closed set in any metric space, let alone a normed linear space.

Comment: He only talks about a ball $B_X$...

Comment: If you are using the book by Haim Brezis, that uses the notation $B_X$, then it is referring to the *closed* unit ball.